# rails_admin подключить Simple Markdown editing

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Как в rails_admin подключить Simple Markdown editing?

Например: в rails_admin подключение  ck_editor имеет такой вид:

```
rails_admin do
    edit do
      ...
      field :description, :ck_editor
    end
  end
```

Но, чтобы подключить "Simple Markdown editing" необходимо добавить к хтмл data-provide="markdown". Как это организовать?